# Checkbox Label Clarity

Tags: usability, copywriting, labels

I have a checkbox that is used to toggle a filter on a returned set of data displayed on the page.  The data consists of rows of media items (i.e. photos, video, docs) each with a date range during which time they are considered "live" and are visible to users.

The current label for the checkbox is "Show Live".  Once checked, any media that has an end date in the past is removed from the display.

My question is about the label text specifically.  Is "Show Live" clear enough?  Should the label include a noun to indicate what is live, such as "Show Live Content"?

I realize this could have subjective answers, but I would appreciate input on the norms and standards for this type of labeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really does depend on your users and their context using your software.

**Unless the concept of "being live" is well understood for the users (because they have learned what it means by using your app), I think you need to find a better way of phrasing it.**

I'd consider:

1. thinking about other ways to phrase it and doing usability testing
2. when you talk with users during the usability test, you can ask questions to uncover users' mental models and what words they would use to describe what you are calling "live"